# Parsing Error Javascript in php include page on the test server

Tags: php, javascript

We're getting this error in our test environment:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in /home/usaspo5/public_html/dev/usgnew/components/com_usg_programs/tmpls/default.php

We have the same code on the live site and it does not produce these results.

Comment: Does your live site have errors turned on?

Comment: I do not believe so. Is there anyway around this. I need to be able to use that page for search feature testing

Comment: I turned off the error reporting and it did nothing for the issue on the test site

Comment: check the versions of PHP on each server

Comment: They're the same Server. So they have the same php version. I misspoke We use it as a test server but it's more of a test environment

Comment: @user11029 Please show your javascript and how it is being delivered to joomla.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a simple error. You have an extra quote or double qoute in your code like this:

```
"function(){"var x=jQuery('#id') "
```

In PHP you can only use var keyword in class to define variable! so, it seems that you have String break some were in js code within php file OR you did not close php tag like `?>` before js code

Comment: Okay, would php asp code <%%> cause issues when using var?

Comment: According to php documentation the ASP tags <%, %>, <%=, and the script tag <script language="php"> are removed from PHP ver 7.0.0. If you use php ver 7 asp tags will not work

Comment: We are using 5.4.0 and <script type="text/html">